# How to remove this weird dashed gap in ReactJS with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm building an app using NextJS - Bootstrap, when I check the elements tab, I see this weird dashed gap on the top of the screen. There is no element that has margin/padding-top at all It's not clickable at all.

Seems like the element with the d-flex class (flex element) has this weird dashed gap. But when I check the elements, this flex element does not any padding or margin.

[image]

In the above picture, there is an image at the top. By default, it should be positioned at the top of the screen. But somehow, there is this dashed gap. I can't use negative `margin-top` values on the image because it won't be the same for all resolutions, it'll break the responsiveness of the app.

I tried `margin: 0 and padding: 0` for almost every component at the top (wrapper divs, the Image component, Html, body, etc.) nothing works.

Why there is this gap and where does it come from?

Edit: After comments, here are the related CSS parts

**This is the parent element** (using Bootstrap class d-flex, it's on the picture above)

```
.main-all-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

**This is the image element**

```
.main-image-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}
```

**Body and HTML**

```
HTML,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
```

Comment: That's weird! try to remove image and see if the gap is still there or just render the page with a simple div to check for the gap.

Comment: Can you post the full CSS properties of the offending element as well as the full CSS properties of the parent.

Comment: I've just edited the question with CSS properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with class `d-flex` has property `justify-content: center` from the look of the class `justify-content-center`, and `flex-direction: column` from the look of `flex-column` class which results in your content pushed to the center vertically if there is available space. You should instead use the class `justify-content-between` instead of `justify-content-center` which will push the image to the top and have the remaining space shared in between the flex child.